# Webcam to BlobURL for Video Playback

Tags: javascript, webrtc, blazor

I am developing an app in Blazor/HTML/JavaScript. I'm trying to get the users webcam into a stream that I can access by identifier because this is a server app, and the request is sent, then when the user allows, a callback is issued. So I cannot use

```
.then(function (stream) {
            vid.srcObject = stream;
 })
```

because at this point the video element does not exist and the server must create it so I need to "hold" that stream there for a few moments until the server can create a video element for it. I have tried to create a BlobURL but the video element events never fire, or I get errors such as "The media resource indicated by the src attribute or assigned media provider object was not suitable."

```
navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia ||
        navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
        navigator.mozGetUserMedia;


if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
    var video = document.getElementById("video1");

    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true })
        .then(function (stream) {         
            console.log("got stream =" + stream);
            return stream;
        })
        .then(stream => new Response(stream))
        .then(response => response.blob())
        .then(blob => window.URL.createObjectURL(blob))
        .then(function (url) {              
            console.log("got url =" + url);
            var vid = document.getElementById("video1");
                        
            vid.src = url; // No errors, onloadstart only, no other events
            vid.load();
          
            vid.oncanplay = function (e) {
                console.log("oncanplay");  // Does not fire
            };
            vid.onloadstart = function (e) {
                console.log("onloadstart");   // Fires but thats it
            };
            vid.onloadedmetadata = function (e) {
                console.log("onloadedmetadata");    // Does not fire
            };
            document.getElementById("video1").oncanplaythrough = function (e) {
                console.log("oncanplaythrough");  // Does not fire
            };
            document.getElementById("video1").onloadeddata = function (e) {
                console.log("onloadeddata");   // Does not fire
                // vid.play();
            };  
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log("got error =" + err);
            return err;
        });



 }
```

Since these video elements are created dynamically I must get it to work with a stream or blob URL because the server handles everything. (The Blazor way).

Comment: That very unclear why you can just keep the variable `stream` the same way you would have held the blob:// URI. You second snippet doesn't wait for anything from the server either.

Comment: The 2nd snippet gives example that assigning blob url to video doesnt work even if there is no delay. Blazor does not use javascript and the video element is a serverside reference created after user grants permission. The url would be passed to the server and assigned to newly created video element

Comment: Creating a blob:// URI from a MediaStream has been deprecated since a few years now. The correct way to feed a video element with a mediastream is to set it as the `srcObject` attribute. But even though was still supported, a blob:// URI is only accessible to the instance that did create it (i.e the browser). Passing a blob:// URI to a server is useless. But, even though I don't know blazor, I'm pretty sure this video element is being rendered by the browser at the end of the day. That's where you need to pass the mediastream as srcObject.